# How to pass a flag from one script to a function in another script

Tags: bash, shell, bash-script, subshell

I have a script that installs a bunch of programs (homebrew, git, etc) and I have it log to `stdout` all the things that its doing along the way, but I want the ability to pass a flag, such as `--no-log` to turn off the logging.  The logging functions are sourced from a file that has a bunch of helper scripts and I'm having trouble getting the flag to pass around to these other files.

[EDIT]

**Given** (./bin/install.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Test for known flags
for opt in $@
do
    case $opt in
        --no-log) export SILENT=true ;;
        -*|--*) 
            e_warning "Invalid option $opt" 
            run_help
            ;;
    esac
done

source ./lib/utils

e_process "Installing Homebrew"
ruby -e "$(curl -#fkL raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

**and** (./lib/utils.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logging() {
    # write your test however you want; this just tests if SILENT is non-empty
    if [ -n "$SILENT" ]; then
        "$@" &> /dev/null
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

# Command/Processing logging
e_process() {
    logging printf "$(tput setaf 6)┃ $(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 7)%s...$(tput sgr0)\n" "$@"
}
```

**Then**

If I run `./bin/dotfiles` I expect to see the logging `┃ Installing Homebrew...`, but if I run `./bin/dotfiles --no-log` I expect to not see the logging, however its not working.

**Output** (using `bash -x`)

```
$ bash -x ./bin/install.sh
+ source ./lib/utils.sh
+ e_process 'Installing Homebrew'
++ tput setaf 6
++ tput sgr0
++ tput setaf 7
++ tput sgr0
+ logging printf '┃ %s...\n' 'Installing Homebrew'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ printf '┃ %s...\n' 'Installing Homebrew'
┃ Installing Homebrew...
```

Using the `--no-log`

```
bash -x ./bin/install.sh --no-log
+ for opt in '$@'
+ case $opt in
+ export SILENT=true
+ SILENT=true
+ source ./lib/utils.sh
+ e_process 'Installing Homebrew'
++ tput setaf 6
++ tput sgr0
++ tput setaf 7
++ tput sgr0
+ logging printf '┃ %s...\n' 'Installing Homebrew'
+ '[' -n true ']'
+ printf '┃ %s...\n' 'Installing Homebrew'
```

Comment: I don't see where, in the install script, you source the utils script. How does install.sh know how to execute `e_process`?

Comment: Sorry @glennjackman, the script does actually source the file, so I edited to add it in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You source the utils script **before** you set the value of the environment variable, so the global variable `$silent_mode` is empty.

Don't use a "temp" variable in the utils script, stick to `$SILENT` in those functions.

Comment: Similarly, in the install script, you don't need the `no_log` var: just `export SILENT=true` in the case branch.

Comment: I've edited the scripts above to reflect the changes, but it still doesn't appear to suppress the logging.  When I'm testing this, I'm running bash on OSX 10.9 from within the scripts directory (`./bin/dotfiles --no-log`) and it still shows all print statments.

Comment: run your script with `bash -x` and see what bash is doing

Comment: added to the example above, using `bash -x`